# Are Recurrent Neural Networks a chain of Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network

I am asking if Recurrent Neural Networks are a chain of Neural Networks.

Now, intuitively an RNN is a Neural Network with a feedback loop from the past outputs and depending on one's implementation a feedback loop from the hidden Layers to the next timestamp's hidden Layer and/or inputs.

Excluding the implementation in which it links the hidden layers, is this implementation any different from a chain of Neural Networks?

[image: RNN]
I think, from my understanding that an implementation like this could be built from a chain of Neural Networks where each input of the NN is the timestamp of the given data  + the output of the last timestamp.

Would you know if this intuition is correct? Or is there any differences in RNNs and ANNs that I am missing?

I have also asked my professor who specializes in Machine Learning this question, and if anyone is curious enough I can see if I can post his response once I get one.

Answer (score 3):

There are two important modifications/differences:

1. You have to **share parameters** of your "chain of neural net" to make it behave like a recurrent neural net.
2. Your "unfold" grows over time - meaning that in first iteration your "chain" has length 1. In second - length 2, after N steps - length N.

If you don't mind these two differences, the unfolded model is pretty much the same thing as a recurrent net. Given the fact that you store all required data in some buffer (since you will need "outdated" outputs/labels etc. during updates).

Comment: How is generating an unfolding type Neural Network any different then creating a mult-input NN that sets the unused parameters to 0?

Comment: (Assuming you are using the sigmoid activation function)

Comment: This has nothing to do with sigmoids. The difference is given in the answer - you need to **share** parameters, if you treat this as a multi-column net - then you need to share parameters across columns. And your unfolding grows over time (thus size of your "big net" too). Of course in terms of RNN their memory requirements also grow as you need to store intermediate activations during training (you do not need to during execution, though).

Answer (score -2):

Most beginners in Neural Network have the assumption that neural network can be discussed on a clean theoretical level in neighborhood to A* pathplanning, C++ programming and Turing-Maschines. Thats totally wrong, Neural Network are a topic of biological neuroscience and her usage is Brain-Computer-Interfaces. The definition what neural networks are, and what type is better is not given by computerscientists, it is coming from the research with animal experiments (monkeys, rats) and the needs of medical research for prosthesis on humans.

A concrete paper which can answer the question what a recurrent neural network is and what the limits are is: [A recurrent neural network for closed-loop intracortical brain–
machine interface decoders](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3638090/pdf/nihms-463228.pdf) In this paper electroded are implanted in a monkey brain, and the recurrent neural network act as a BCI for interpreting the monkeys brain. On the other hand: if no biological lifeform is in the loop, it makes no sense to use a neural network at all.

I know, that this is only a indirect answer to the OP, but my valid excuse is that most of the papers on pubmed.gov are not available as OpenAccess so that a further research is left open.

Comment: Artificial Neural Nets were certainly inspired by the brain, and they can be applied to neuroscience applications.  But you don't need a physical brain to use an ANN any more than you need a set of Petri dishes to do evolutionary computing.   Besides, the ANNs in that paper aren't being used to simulate a brain; they're being used to map specific electrical signals to kinematic data for monkey arms.  There are plenty of non-bio-inspired algorithms that could be used for that (They use some sort of Kalman Filter for the baseline). And ANNs can be used for non-brain-related nonlinear mappings.